# Typescript generics, get type of Array contents

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I've built a method that will concatentate an array with another array that's passed in.  The array lives on a parent object called `state` which is generically typed in my method.

My method is along the lines of this:

```js
export const mutateConcat = <T, K extends keyof T>(state: T, key: K, val: T[K]) => {
  ((state[key] as unknown) as any[]) = ((state[key] as unknown) as any[]).concat(val);
}
```

Obviously this is ugly, and I'd like to get rid of the casting to `unknown` and `any[]`.  I'd also like to be able to determine the type of the array contents.

Basically, I need to ensure that T[K] is an Array, and ideally I'd like to assign the type of the contents of the array to another generic parameter, say `U`.

I have tried `<T, K extends keyof T, U extends Array<T[K]>>` but that assigns `U` to the type of the array itself, not to the type of the contents of the array.

Is what I'm asking possible?  Can `extends keyof` be filtered to only keys that are array types, and can the types of the contents of those arrays be assigned to another type parameter?

Thanks in advance

Edit: 
So, I've managed to get the type of the array by keying off of the `val` variable.  So the following:

```js
export const mutateConcat = <T, U, K extends keyof T>(state: T, key: K, val: T[K] & U[], arrayDistinctProperty?: keyof U) => {
  // U now contains the array type, and `arrayDistinctProperty` is typed to a property on that array type object
  ((state[key] as unknown) as any[]) = ((state[key] as unknown) as any[]).concat(val);
}
```

However, this doesn't solve the ugliness of the casting, because typescript doesn't know for sure that `T[K]` is an array type.  Is it possible to tell it to only allow my `key` parameter to be an array type on `T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, between this and a reddit thread I believe I have the best solution for my needs. Here is what I've come up with:

```
const mutateConcat = <
  TState extends Record<TKey, any[]>,  
  TKey extends keyof TState,  
  TElement extends TState[TKey] extends Array<infer TEl> ? TEl : never  
>(state: TState, key: TKey, val: T[K], elementProperty?: keyof TElement) => { 
  state[key].push(...val);
  if (elementProperty) {
    // filter state[key] to have distinct values off of element property
  }
}
```

I chose to use `any[]` in the `TState` because there were other issues when I tried `TElement[]` because the state could have any kinds of properties on them and it was not aligning with the way it was being called.  This method is actually being used as a vuex mutation method as a higher order function so I'm not concerned with extreme type safety on the state parameter.  The `keyof` parameters are the important ones as those will be passed by developers, and this solution enforces that both are valid for the objects being passed.

Edit: Here's the full function for anyone interested:

```
const mutateConcat = <
  TState extends Record<TKey, any[]>,
  TKey extends keyof TState,
  TElement extends TState[TKey] extends Array<infer TEl> ? TEl : never
>(
  key: TKey,
  sessionKey?: string,
  distinctProperty?: keyof TElement,
) => (state: TState, val: TElement[]) => {
  state[key].push(...val);

  if (distinctProperty) {
    removeDuplicates(state[key], distinctProperty);
  }

  if (sessionKey) {
    setSessionItem(sessionKey, state);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct, but I wanted to add that you can get it to work if you make `state` a relatively concrete `Record<K, U[]>` type, instead of the more generic `T extends Record<K, U[]>` type.  This helps the compiler see the assignment as safe, since `T extends {a: string[]}` could be `{a: Array<"lit">}`, and then `obj.a.push("oops")` would be an error:

```
const mutateConcat = <K extends keyof any, U>(
  state: Record<K, U[]>,
  key: K,
  val: U[]
) => {
  state[key] = state[key].concat(val); // okay
};
```

The only problem I see there is if you pass object literals into the `state` parameter when you call `mutateConcat()`, you will get presumably undesirable [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) on non-array properties:

```
mutateConcat({ a: [1, 2, 3], b: 1 }, "a", [4, 5, 6]); // excess property checking
```

And anything I do to the signature of `mutateConcat()` to address this causes the compiler to be too confused inside the implementation and you're back to <strike>casting</strike> [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  If you still want to go this way you can avoid excess property checking by not using fresh object literals, as in:

```
const obj = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: 1 };
mutateConcat(obj, "a", [4, 5, 6]); // okay
```

Whether this satisfies your use case is up to you.  Okay, good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgVygQygUwMLmKmBeGAHgGkY0APdMAEwhgGs0BPEAMxmTCYBoYBVAHwAKAFAwY0VGgBcMAEppQAJ2olefANoBdAdzENms4nvEA3ZABtZmrSICU+ATADe+yeg2MmW-BJQevLQA6UDAcKCFzCzsAbhEAXziRRH9MbFQhZw5ZDQBGXgAmXgBmLV4AI1lcmHjeACJkOt4NABZeAFZeADYtWJgAen6ycmA0CDoAByUQCbQlKCYYYAALRXoASzAAcxhAXg3AIj2REVDoGBBygCtfLOQc-JgimFKKqpq4lKksMIzzi-rG5ptGCdGA9PqDM70ZBMERAA)

Comment: The `keyof any` is new to me. Neat. What is its advantage of simply doing `K extends string` in this situation?

Comment: One limitation in this is that it does not pass this test: `const obj = { a: [1, 2, 3] }; mutateConcat(obj, "a", [ 1, 'b', 'c' ]);`, which I assumed should be an error, because I had assumed that the target type of the array comes from the state not from the new values.

Answer (score 1):

#### Approach #1

```
/**
 * Push into the existing array.
 */
export const mutateConcat1 = <
  TState extends Record<TKey, unknown[]>,
  TKey extends string,
  >(
    state: TState,
    key: TKey,
    newArray: TState[TKey]
  ) => {
  state[key].push(...newArray);
};
```

#### Approach #2

The cast with `as` here might be unavoidable. Without it we receive, **Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'TState[TKey]'.** That is because we told the compiler that the array is of type `unknown[]` in the `Record`. I tried to `infer` the array type but was not able to make it work. The cast seems very safe though, given that we know for sure that both `state[key]` and `newArray` are of the same type. If only I knew how to explain that to the compiler.

```
/**
 * Overwrite the original array with concat.
 */
export const mutateConcat2 = <
  TState extends Record<TKey, unknown[]>,
  TKey extends string,
  >(
    state: TState,
    key: TKey,
    newArray: TState[TKey]
  ) => {
  state[key] = state[key].concat(newArray) as TState[TKey];
};
```

#### Testing

```
/**
 * Test Cases
 */

const goodState = { array1: [1, 2, 3] };
const badState = { array1: new Date() };

// ok
mutateConcat1(goodState, 'array1', [4, 5, 6]);
mutateConcat2(goodState, 'array1', [4, 5, 6]);

// errors
mutateConcat1(goodState, 'array1', ['4', 5, 6]);
mutateConcat1(goodState, 'array2', [4, 5, 6]);
mutateConcat1(badState, 'array1', [4, 5, 6]);

mutateConcat2(goodState, 'array1', ['4', 5, 6]);
mutateConcat2(goodState, 'array2', [4, 5, 6]);
mutateConcat2(badState, 'array1', [4, 5, 6]);
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PQKhCgAIUgFBXAzgC0gSwHYBcD2kvICmkhAHmolpgOaQCGATg3QJ4B0UIw4ZADjgyyQAxjgyVIAW3hY6WQgGExwuQEZIAXkgAeKJAAqAZVnySpeRgAmiSACVCohpe36A0oRYAaSPAwBrDBwAdwwAbQBdAD5PPTcPMwtrSEoGGhjISEiACj0MyjlCAC4DYwL0jMg-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-MDkM3NC-yfXUgA).